I can't access the admin page in my router, is there a way to install a new firmware? router model : ZTE ZXHM F6600P
I wanted to turn my router into an AP, but apparently the option to activate it has been locked by my ISP, since I can't access the 192.168.0.1 page, I can only log in 192.168.11.1 as a user. After I looked online, I tried to find another firmware, but no luck. I also tried to look for a way to turn the firmware into a lunix based one (OpenWRT and DD-WRT) but i couldn't find one that's compatible with my router. Do you have any ideas to bypass this?
